# RestSharp POST Commit with GitLab-API

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, gitlab-api

I am trying to send a Multifile commit to the [GitLab API](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions).

I'm passing authorization and getting a `BadRequest` response. I've validated my `JSON` but I'm getting this in the response

> "{"error":"branch is missing, commit_message is missing, actions is missing"}"

**JSON**

```
{
    "branch": "master",
    "commit_message": "Ticket-27 6\/29\/2017 4:37:13 PM",
    "author_name": "My Name",
    "author_email": "myName@myCompany.com",
    "actions": [{
            "action": "create",
            "file_path": "procedures\/dbo.sp_SomeProc1.sql",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n-- =============================================\r\n-- Author:\t\t<,,Name>\r\n-- Create date: <Create Date,,>\r\n-- Description:\t<Description,,>\r\n-- =============================================\r\n\r\nCREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SomeProc1] @ID int,@StartDate datetime\r\n\t-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here\r\n\r\nAS\r\nBEGIN\r\n\r\n\tSET NOCOUNT ON;\r\n\tSELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MEMBERID = @ID \r\n\t"
        }, {
            "action": "create",
            "file_path": "procedures\/dbo.sp_SomeProc2.sql",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n-- =============================================\r\n-- Author:\t\t<,,Name>\r\n-- Create date: <Create Date,,>\r\n-- Description:\t<Description,,>\r\n-- =============================================\r\n\r\nCREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SomeProc2] @ID int,@StartDate datetime\r\n\t-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here\r\n\r\nAS\r\nBEGIN\r\n\r\n\tSET NOCOUNT ON;\r\n\tSELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MEMBERID = @ID \r\n\t"
        }, {
            "action": "create",
            "file_path": "procedures\/dbo.sp_SomeProc3.sql",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n-- =============================================\r\n-- Author:\t\t<,,Name>\r\n-- Create date: <Create Date,,>\r\n-- Description:\t<Description,,>\r\n-- =============================================\r\n\r\nCREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SomeProc3] @ID int,@StartDate datetime\r\n\t-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here\r\n\r\nAS\r\nBEGIN\r\n\r\n\tSET NOCOUNT ON;\r\n\tSELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MEMBERID = @ID \r\n\t"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then changed the content to be `"test"` but I get a different error I believe from RestSharp.

- `StatusCode = 0`
- `ErrorMessage = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

**JSON**

```
{
    "branch": "master",
    "commit_message": "Ticket-27 6\/29\/2017 4:37:13 PM",
    "author_name": "My Name",
    "author_email": "myName@myCompany.com",
    "actions": [{
            "action": "create",
            "file_path": "procedures\/dbo.sp_SomeProc1.sql",
            "content": "test"
        }, {
            "action": "create",
            "file_path": "procedures\/dbo.sp_SomeProc2.sql",
            "content": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally, my `C#` code:

```
RestRequest request = 
    new RestRequest($@"api/v4/projects/{project.id}/repository/commits", Method.POST);

request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    ContentType = "application/json", 
    Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, 
    Value = commit 
});

request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    Name = "PRIVATE-TOKEN", 
    Type = ParameterType.HttpHeader, 
    Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitLabPrivateToken"] 
});

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

IRestResponse respone = _restClient.Execute(request);
```

Now, the `"file_path"` actually doesn't exist on the branch, but I thought since I was taking a `"create"` action it wouldn't need to be.

**EDIT**
Stack trace of the `StatusCode = 0`

```
at RestSharp.RestClient.<ConfigureHttp>b__2f(Parameter p2)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at RestSharp.RestClient.ConfigureHttp(IRestRequest request, IHttp http)
at RestSharp.RestClient.Execute(IRestRequest request, String httpMethod, Func`3 getResponse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the name of the parameter for my `JSON` request parameter needed to be `application/json`. After the change, worked fine. Here is the final `C#` code:

```
RestRequest request = 
    new RestRequest($@"api/v4/projects/{project.id}/repository/commits", Method.POST);

request.Parameters.Clear();

request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    Name = "application/json", 
    ContentType = "application/json", 
    Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, 
    Value = commit 
});
request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    Name = "PRIVATE-TOKEN", 
    Type = ParameterType.HttpHeader, 
    Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GitLabPrivateKey"] 
});

IRestResponse respone = _restClient.Execute(request);
```

Amazing how something so small will drive you bonkers for hours.